# How to send requests on the dynamic url in the TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(threadGroup())?

Tags: java, jmeter, dsl

I need to create a performance test on the full operation flow with the several APIs.

httpSampler(urlForFirstRequest) and its children (new DslJsr223PostProcessor("Save url parameter from the response of the first request") - work correctly and provide an URL for the second request. Provided URLs are different for each separate thread as it needed.

The problem is: how to create code for sending the second request (on the place "httpSampler(urlForSecondRequest)") where each separate thread of the test will receive different URLs from the first request (parameter "urlForSecondRequest" is dynamic and the second request should be sent to this saved value)?

```
TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
        threadGroup(testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getLoadTime()),
                httpSampler(urlForFirstRequest)
                        .method(POST)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .header(AUTHORIZATION, getAuthToken())
                        .body(someBodyForFirstRequest)
                        .children(
                                new DslJsr223PostProcessor("Save url parameter from the response of the first request",
                                        "def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());\n" +
                                                "def urlForSecondRequest = jsonResponse.links[1].href;\n" +
                                                "vars.put('urlForSecondRequest', urlForSecondRequest);")
                                ),
                httpSampler(urlForSecondRequest)
                        .method(POST)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .header(AUTHORIZATION, getAuthToken())
                        .body(someBodyForSecondRequest)
                        .children(
                                new DslJsr223PostProcessor("Save token parameter from the response of the second request",
                                        "def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());\n" +
                                                "def token = jsonResponse.token;\n" +
                                                "vars.put('response', token);")
                        ),
                new DslJsr223Sampler("Print result",
                        "String result = vars.get('response')" +
                                "if (result != null) {\n" +
                                "    println(result);\n" +
                                "} else {\n" +
                                "    println('result not found');\n" +
                                "}")
        ).rampTo(testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getRumpUpTime())),
        influxDbListener(envSetting.getInfluxDbUrl())
                .measurement("someMeasurement")
).run();
```

The code of print result needed to see if the code will works correctly. The parameter "response" will be different for each thread.

I already tried to use httpSampler("${urlForSecondRequest}") but the result is failed.

How do I send requests on the dynamic URL which provided from the response of the first request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set the path of the 2nd HTTP Request sampler to the JMeter Variable which is generated by 1st HTTP Request sampler you need to use the following syntax:

```
httpSampler("${urlForSecondRequest}")
```

In case if "the result is failed":

- check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
- instead of testPlan.run() call [testPlan.saveAsJmx() function](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/guide/#save-as-jmx), add [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and see what is the value of your `${urlForSecondRequest}` variable